# Angular test method call is not setting variables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am trying to learn Jasmine, and I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. When I run this test case, on the line `expect(component.roleModal.visible).toBeTrue();` I get an error saying `Expected false to be true`.

```js
describe('ManageRolesComponent', () => {
  let component: ManageRolesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ManageRolesComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],
      providers: [HttpClient, HttpHandler],
      declarations: [ManageRolesComponent, RoleModalComponent],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ManageRolesComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should open the add modal', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'onOpenAdd').and.callThrough();
    expect(component.roleModal.visible).toBeTrue();
    expect(component.roleModal.state).toBe(ModalRoleState.Add);
  });
});
```

The function `onOpenAdd()` is pretty simple:

```
  public onOpenAdd() {
    this.roleModal.state = ModalRoleState.Add;
    this.roleModal.open();
  }
```

Same with `open()`:

```
  public open() {
    this.visible = true;
  }
```

When the test executes it fails why is this? Am I doing this correctly? I am setting the value `visible` explicitly to `true` so why is the test false?

Comment: Do you use `ngOnInit` on your component?

Comment: @Roy yes I do...

Comment: I think you are missing the initialisation of the component itself between the `spyOn` and `expect`: `component.ngOnInit();`

Comment: It seems as if after the `spyOn` I must explicitly run `component.onOpenAdd();`. I assumed that is what `.and.callThrough();` did...

Comment: No, the `and.callThrough()` is needed, _the spy will still track all calls to it but in addition it will delegate to the actual implementation._ You could also return directly a value.

Answer (score 0):

to make your test work:

delete change detection from beforeEach

```
beforeEach(() => {
 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ManageRolesComponent);
 component = fixture.componentInstance;
 // fixture.detectChanges(); delete this
});
```

and place your change detection call just after your spy

```
it('should open the add modal', () => {
 spyOn(component, 'onOpenAdd').and.callThrough();
 fixture.detectChanges();
 expect(component.roleModal.visible).toBeTrue();
 expect(component.roleModal.state).toBe(ModalRoleState.Add);
});
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue. I still get the same error.